# Why jdbc executing sqlserver proceduce takes 10 min but navicat or ssms only 50s?

Tags: sql-server, database, jdbc, ssms, navicat

I use sqlserver-jdbc driver execute query in java, have wait about 700s before returning result set, but it's only 50s when I do this with navicat or SSMS instead. Anybody has similar problem, I can't find reason since I don't know datebase much,.

Comment: We'll need some more info to help. Show us some code, what query is running slow?

Answer (score 0):

Use that script to get cached execution plans of your SP:

```
SELECT cp.objtype AS ObjectType,
OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid,st.dbid) AS ObjectName,
cp.usecounts AS ExecutionCount,
st.TEXT AS QueryText,
qp.query_plan AS QueryPlan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) AS qp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) AS st
WHERE objtype ='Proc' AND OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid,st.dbid) = '__YOUR_SP_NAME__';
```

I suppose that SSMS and sqlserver-jdbc driver use different cached plans.